# Recursive method for reading files not working

Tags: java

I have this method here, I want to look in a folder recursively to count files that startsWith "D".

It is showing me the `StackOverflowError`.

```
public void CountThem() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
           int count = 0;
        File []files = file.listFiles();

        for(File f : files){
            if(f.isDirectory()){
                CountThem();
            }else{
                if(f.getName().startsWith("D")){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change the signature countThem() to countThem(File file)
And check how can you accumulate counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when a `File` is a directory, you're starting over your function, that makes an infinite loop. You would have to define the function, that takes a `File` as a parameter:

```
public int countThem(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    int count = 0;
    File []files = file.listFiles();

    for(File f : files){
        if(f.isDirectory()) {
            count += countThem(f);
        } else {
            if(f.getName().startsWith("D")) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

P.S.: In java it's a standard to start method names lowercase.

Edit:

```
public class Fajlla {

    File folder;
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;
    public Fajlla(String fld)throws IOException{
        folder = new File(fld);
        if(!folder.isDirectory()){
            throw new IOException("Nuk eshte folder");
        }
        pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/dreniii.txt"));
    }

        public int callItOUU() throws IOException{
            return this.countThem(folder);
        }


    public int countThem(File folder){
           int count = 0;
            File [] files = folder.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                  if(file.isDirectory()){
                      count+=countThem(file);
                  }if(file.isFile() && file.canRead()){
                      count++;
                  }
        }
            return count;
    }




        public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Fajlla  f = new Fajlla("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/New folder");
            int count = f.callItOUU(new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/dreniii.txt"));
            System.out.println(count);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Fajlla.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: @Dreni so what's the problem?

Comment: it showing the same errorr , i ll post the full code wait

Comment: @Dreni you've made a mistake when copying my answer. I wrote `countThem(f)`, in your case it will be `countThem(file)`.

Comment: but i am doing the same thing in the callitOuu method

Comment: **public int callItOUU() throws IOException{
            return this.countThem(folder);
        }**

Comment: Why can't you use the function, that I have written?

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code

```
 public class Fajlla {

    File folder;
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;
    public Fajlla(String fld)throws IOException{
        folder = new File(fld);
        if(!folder.isDirectory()){
            throw new IOException("Nuk eshte folder");
        }
        pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/dreniii.txt"));
    }

        public int callItOUU() throws IOException{
            return this.countThem(folder);
        }


    public int countThem(File folder){
           int count = 0;
            File [] files = folder.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                  if(file.isDirectory()){
                      count+=countThem(folder);
                  }if(file.isFile() && file.canRead()){
                      count++;
                  }
        }
            return count;
    }




        public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Fajlla  f = new Fajlla("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/New folder");
            int count = f.callItOUU();
            System.out.println(count);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Fajlla.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }


}
```